# Screenshot of window is taking too long

Tags: iphone, ios

I am taking the screenshot of the app window on user's tap action using the following code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.window.bounds.size, self.view.opaque, 0.0);
[self.view.window.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() CGImage], CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, self.view.window.layer.frame.size.height *2));
```

-performing a few operations on `imageContext`-

```
myImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
```

Now, the screenshot is just fine, but the amount of time it takes to render it is excruciating. I need to present an animation as soon as the user taps, but i cannot begin the animation until the screenshot image is stored in `myImage`.

Is there a speedy way of doing this, like Facebook does on it's wall (when image browser is opened), or are they using some other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to speed up the process a 'little' bit by distributing the tasks between the background and main threads.

I performed the following tasks on the background thread `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
//code
});`  :

- Begin `CGImageContext`
- Create `CGImageRef`
- Create screenshot using `renderInContext`
- Perform the operations on the imageRef i need.
- Pass the final `UIImage` to a `selector`, which further sets the image to the variable i want (`UIImageView` in my case) .
- End and Release the graphics contexts.

In the `selector` in invoked at the end of the block, i set the image to the `UIImageView` using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//code

    });`